# Linear Algebra Question on Linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a, b ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$ be two linearly independent vectors and $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}^* $ be two non-zero scalars.

1. What is the rank of the matrix $A= [a \,\alpha a\, b \,\beta b] $ ?

For this question since the rank of the matrix would be the number of linearly independent vectors, I came to a conclusion that the rank would be 2.

2. Can you name two linearly independent vectors $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^4$ in the null space of M (i.e. $Mx = My = 0$) ?

I multiplied the matrix $[a\, αa\, b\, βb] \cdot [x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4]^T$
and equated the solution to $0$ (Nullspace).

**Yet the final equation I get cannot be expressed in terms of a linear combination of 2 independent vectors. Is there something wrong with my approach? Or how would I be able to do the same?**

Comment: For the first question: what if $\;\alpha=\beta\;$ ?

Comment: Assume α is not = β

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you know that the rank of $A$ is the dimension of the subspace 
\begin{align}<a,\alpha a,b,\beta b>&=\{qa+r\alpha a+s b+t\beta b\,;\,(q,r,s,t)\in\mathbb{R}^4\}\\&=\{(q+r\alpha)a+(s+t\beta)b\,;\,(q,r,s,t)\in\mathbb{R}^4\}\\&=\{q'a+r'b\,;\,(q',r')\in\mathbb{R}^2\}\\&=\,<a,b>,\end{align}
which is of dimension $2$ by assumption.

In the second question, you know according to  Rank Theorem that : 
$$\dim \ker M=\dim\mathbb{R}^4-\mathrm{rank}\, M=2,$$ so you have indeed two linearly independant vectors $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb{R}^4$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^4$ in $\ker M$. Two such vectors are given in terms of coordinates by the equation 
$$Ax=0\iff x_1a+x_2\alpha a+x_3b+x_4\beta b=0,$$ so you can take by example $x=(\alpha,-1,0,0)$ and $y=(0,0,\beta,-1)$, which are linearly independant.

Comment: I agree with what you did but I was told that the solution for the second part of the question is [α,-1, 0 , 0 ] and [0, 0 , β, -1). Is this wrong or is there a different approach to get the above mentioned solution?

Comment: It is an error from my part, I will correct this quickly !

Comment: Could you perhaps indicate as to how "x=(α,−1,0,0) and y=(0,0,β,−1)" are obtained from the equation numerically.

Comment: I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I'm still pretty  confused with the final solution!

Comment: Because the dot product of the Matrix and x would equate to zero and x2 and x4 can be taken as free variables and if you were to express [x1 x2 x3 x4] as a linear combination of 2 independent vectors, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I get the equations x1 = -αx2 -b/a x3 + βb x4 and x3 = -βx4 - αa/b x2 - a/bx1. If i try to express [x1 x2 x3 x4]^T, due to the coefficients of x3 in the first equation and x1 in the second equation, I'm unable to express it as a linear combination of two vectors! @Baloown

Comment: What I do at the end is just see that, if in a first time I take $x_3=x_4=0$, I have the equation $x_1 a+x_2 \alpha a=0\iff (x_1+x_2\alpha)a=0\iff x_1=-x_2\alpha$ (this last equivalence come from $a$ is non-zero vector). I take a particular solution of this equation, namely $x_1=\alpha$ and $x_2=-1$, to get a non-zero vector of $\ker M$. I do the same work concentrating this time on the vector $b$, to finally get my solution.

Comment: You can't divide by $a$ ! These are vectors. A thing you can do in a first time to well-manipulate these objects is to use some notations : here I think that you were confused by the equation $x_1a+...+x_4\beta b=0$, which is an equation between vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ! The notation $0=0_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ would be more precise in a first time.